# Two Windows Server Session using the same Glassfish Server

Tags: glassfish, windows-server-2012, glassfish-4

I'm deploying an application on Glassfish Server on a Windows10 machine via a remote Desktop connection. What would happen if another user deploys another version of the application on the same Glassfish Server ( the same port obviously) while the other session is still active ?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the session alvive during deployments if you check the corresponding checkbox in the admin application.

If do not check this option active sessions will be destroyed.